# Javascript: push a file to an input (file type) element using the files property

Tags: javascript, file-upload

How can I push a file to an input (file type) element using the files property ?

```
element2.files.push(element.files[0]);
```

The code above give me an error:

```
TypeError: element2.files.push is not a function
```

The source can be datatransfer from drag and drop or another input.

Comment: I'm not sure that the question makes sense. I don't think you can set the input. If you want to be able to drag and drop files into the input you handle the `drop` event, like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Selecting_files_using_drag_and_drop). For your other use case, I don't know if it's possible to set an input to the value of another one programmatically though.

Comment: See this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because element2.files is not an Array . So you cannot use push function for add a item into a object as element2.files is a object .
You can check it using :

```
element2.files instanceof Array 
element2.files instanceof Object
```